# Do I need an ESTA or Visa as a spouse of a US citizen, traveling from the UK?

Tags: visas, usa, uk, esta

My husband is a US citizen and I am a Canadian citizen. We both live in the UK and are planning to travel to the US in September. I believe I am eligble to travel to the US (from the UK) because we are 'close family members' and can provide our marriage certificate. However I am unsure about what documentation I need, and whether it's a ESTA or visa or nothing at all. We will only be in the US for 5 days.
Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.
Thanks,
Nicole

Comment: Have you checked the official websites yet? [The Travel.State.gov site](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visa-waiver-program.html) has pretty comprehensive information on the Visa Waiver Program

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have checked and it appears I may need a visa, given I am a Canadian citizen. However I travel to the US regularly and have not applied for a visa before, so I wanted to double check if anyone had experience. Also this is the first time traveling to the US as someone married to a US citizen. Thanks

Comment: Did you also read [this page](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/citizens-of-canada-and-bermuda.html) on Citizens of Canada?

Comment: Yes thanks! As suspected, I don't think I need a visa as a Canadian citizen.

Comment: The tricky part is that I am traveling from the UK (a banned country for non-citizens). I am a 'close family member' of a US citizen and we are traveling together. But am I subject to any requirements like ESTA? Or anything covid related, aside from the fit-to-fly PCR test?

Comment: I'll write you an answer to make it clearer. COVID-related bans are different than visa requirements

Comment: Canadians do not require visa nor ESTA to enter the US as a "visitor for business or pleasure."  Canada is not listed on the VWP pages because Canada is not a VWP country.  That, however, does not imply that you need a visa: Canadians' visa exemption simply arises from a different (much older) law.

Answer (score 3):

So you have two different factors at play, and I'll answer both of them

### You're Canadian, traveling on a Canadian passport (visa requirement)

[You don't need a visa or ESTA to travel to the US](https://help.cbp.gov/s/article/Article-1094?language=en_US#:%7E:text=No%2C%20citizens%20of%20Canada%20who,a%20Landed%20Immigrant%20of%20Canada%3F)

### You are married to a US citizen and both of you are travelling from the UK (COVID-related ban)

Travelers from the UK were banned from entry under PP 10143 *even those who don't need a visa for entry*

However, the [text of the proclamation](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/presidential-actions/2021/01/25/proclamation-on-the-suspension-of-entry-as-immigrants-and-non-immigrants-of-certain-additional-persons-who-pose-a-risk-of-transmitting-coronavirus-disease/) says that the entry ban doesn't apply to:

(iii)   any noncitizen who is the spouse of a U.S. citizen or lawful permanent resident; (You)

[As recommended by the US Embassy in the UK](https://uk.usembassy.gov/visas/u-s-visa-and-travel-faqs/), carry documentation to prove your exempt status (marriage certificate) and follow your destination state's requirements for quarantine

Comment: The husband is not a non-citizen national.  The proclamation doesn't apply to him because it applies only to aliens.

Comment: @phoog oops, I missed the word "ban" in the answer. I'll correct it

Comment: Thanks very much Juliana! It's been confusing to navigate all the guidance. I'll bring my marriage certificate, a photocopy of his passport and his itinerary (we arent traveling together) and hopefully this will suffice! Really appreciate your help :)